# Bootstrap 3.0 RC2 mixins issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried out the new boostrap and wanted to use the mixins but it seems to have no effect on my page. I also tried the example one from the bootstrap docs which didnt work either.

Mixins

```
.wrapper {
.make-row();
}
.content-main {
  .make-lg-column(8);
}
.content-secondary {
  .make-lg-column(3);
  .make-lg-column-offset(1);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content-main">...</div>
  <div class="content-secondary">...</div>
</div>
```

the result it gave was the content in each div on separate lines instead of on one line with a offset of one column in the middle. How can I get this to work properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your resolution? Bigger than 1200px (`@screen-large`)?

Comment: yes, i am testing it on my 1366x768 monitor with my broswer maximized.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not importing the `bootstrap.less` from the `less` folder. The `less` folder is in the root of the Bootstrap 3 project. I usually take the `less` folder and put it in my project folder and make a `main.less` and import it in there. So lets say that your project folder looks like the following:

[image]

Then your `main.less` would look like this:

```
@import '../less/bootstrap.less';
.wrapper{
   .make-row();
}
.content-main {
  .make-lg-column(8);
}

.content-secondary {
  .make-lg-column(3);
  .make-lg-column-offset(1);
}
```

and in your html you only need to link to the `main.less` file. But the [less.js](https://raw.github.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less-1.4.1.min.js) should be added after linking to the `main.less` file. So the head section would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/main.less" />
<script src="js/less-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the project should be put in the local server (like mamp or xamp) rather than being opened statically by double clicking on the `index.html` file.

Then you should be able to see it working if you have something like the following in your html body:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-main">
        <div class="well">
            <h1>Left</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-secondary">
        <div class="well">
            <h1>Right</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can even improve on it and make it more semantic by using html5 tags. So for example you can use `<section>` to be used for a row `<article>` as columns (but obviously you would need to give your articles specific classes). Something like:

**main.less**

```
@import '../less/bootstrap.less';
section{
  .make-row();
}
.main-content{
  .make-lg-column(5);
}

.secondary{
  .make-lg-column(7);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <article class="main-content">
        <div>
            <h1>Main Content</h1>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="secondary">
        <div>
            <h1>Secondary content</h1>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

I hope that helped you. Happy bootstrapping :D